# tab navigation in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

In my Home screen I've used a TabHost containing a FrameLayout & TabWidget to display 3 tabs.

Clicking on the 1st Tab takes the user to another Activity:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
               res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
               .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

The AlbumsActivity contains a ListView, which shows a list of albums. Clicking on an item, will take the user to yet another activity showing the details.

I want to show the same set of tabs as on the home screen. Should the new activity have another TabHost containing the same TabWidget -OR- is it possible to show the output within the original FrameLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TabActivity?
TabActivity is container and other activities are inside it, other activities don't need TabWidget.

Comment: Yes, I'm using TabActivity. I want to show the 3 tabs across all activities where the user navigates to. Is that possible?